# How to process data on the server with rails and heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, activerecord

I am developing a website using Ruby on Rails and I am doing a bit of rough planning. I can and have deployed rails websites before, just adding to the database and retrieving from database based on my use case, but this time around, its a bit different. I am adding to database but i will need the data to be processed on the server before the data is being sent back to the user or when he decides to retrieve it. What i do not get is how i am going to process the data on the server. I know this doesnt follow the normal pattern for asking questions, i would search for it with google except I dont know what I am looking for. A nudge in the right direction will do.

What I want to do exactly is have users register and click a button (request) which puts the users id in an array , what I need to do on the server is to randomly or not randomly connect two users based on some qualities, this program keeps running infinitely, such that the user can come back later to check if he has been connected with someone already.

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to process but below answer is about correct, that this is usually done in controllers or models. Let us know what exactly you want to do or check the docs.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i just updated my question stating exactly what I want to do

Comment: After reading the edited version, I think this can probably be done easily using a rake task that would add connections to a specific user. You can run a Rake task from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of logic typically belongs in the controller, or perhaps on the models. You should read the Rails docs, particularly on controllers: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you may find a lot of benefit from running a background job for this that is constantly looking for matches. You could have an infinitely running Sidekiq process that is queued up with users. Then once one finishes, just fire it up again.

Or you could create a rake task that does a `User.find_each` and have it run again when the task finishes. But this would make things blocking if you end up having a lot of users. I'd recommend one job per user and just bloat the system with them. This way you can scale out both horizontally and vertically.

You'll want to learn about [ActiveJob](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) and [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) to help achieve what you're looking for :). Sidekiq requires [Redis](https://redis.io/) which you'll also have to setup as well. I'd recommend the [redis-rails](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails) gem to help with the integration.

Answer (score 0):

To go off BenMorganIO's answer, I think this is a job for a background worker. This is a job that is processed in the background, so it doesn't slow up your app. A good example of this is firing off an email in the background.

There are primarily 3 gems I've seen for this:

- [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)
- [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque)
- [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) (just celebrated 5 years!)

Those should point you in the right direction.